shared hosting with cpanel, upload Node application
I'm trying to upload a node application to a shared hosting via cpanel, I have access via ssh, I can use npm to install it, everything is fine, but it's returning an error that I don't know what it is, on my machine and on servers it works smoothly,
see below error when i run npm start:
[ssv/ssv(14)] [ss@d2s3 ssv]$ npm start npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the --scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executedwith.

Servidor@1.0.0 start /home/ss/ssv/ssvts-node --transpileOnly src/server.ts

Server started on port 3334(node:2647718) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeORMError: No 
connection options were found in any orm configuration files.at new TypeORMError 
(/home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/lib/node_modules/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
at ConnectionOptionsReader.<anonymous> 
(/home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/lib/node_modules/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts:46:19)at step 
(/home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:196:27)at Object.next 
(/home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:177:57)at fulfilled 
(/home/vaiugope/nodevenv/servidorPedido/servidorPedido/14/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:167:62)at 
processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)(node:2647718) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
 This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
 or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
 (rejection id: 1)(node:2647718) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
 Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future,
 promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a 
non-zero exit code.`

